# Unexpected behavior when displaying `ShareLink`

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-sharelink

When displaying SwiftUI's `ShareLink` in a Hebrew app, all words in the sheet are flipped horizontally.

[image]

```
ShareLink(item: url) {
  Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
    .padding(10)
}
```

I do not use any of the following:

- `.environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)`
- `.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(false)`

I already tried using `.environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)` and `.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(false)`.
I also tried to look anywhere in my project to see if there's any setting that forces rtl.

What am I doing wrong?